# Cauchy Riemann to find differentiable function

Tags: complex-analysis

Use Cauchy-Reimann equation to determine all differentiable function that satisfy $$\text{Im} f(z)=x^2-y^2$$

what I did:
$$v(x,y)=x^2 - y^2$$

$$u_x= v_y =-2y$$

$$u(x,y) =-x^2 + K(y)$$

$$K'(y)=-2y$$

$$K(y)=-y^2 + D$$

Finally, I got: $$f(x,y)= -x^2 - y^2 + D + i(x^2 -y^2)$$

I don't where I am going wrong and any help will be appreciated. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine until you integrate
$$ u_x = -2y: $$
it is clear that your expression $u=-x^2+K(y)$ does not differentiate to this. What you want is
$$ u = -2xy+K(y), $$
surely; from there, proceed as you did before.

Answer (score 1):

Just see this

$$ u_y = -v_x = -2x \implies u(x,y) = -2 x y + g(x). $$

To determine $g(x)$ we differentiate w.r. to $x$ and use the other equation $u_x=v_y$ I let you finish it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to notice that $(x+iy)^2 = x^2 -y ^2 + 2 i xy$, so
if $f(z) = i z^2$, we have $\operatorname{im} f(x+iy) = x^2-y^2$.

If $\operatorname{im} f(z) = \operatorname{im} g(z)$ for two analytic functions $f,g$ (on some domain) then $f-g$ is a constant.

Since we see that $\operatorname{im} f(0) = 0$, we see that the constant must be real.  Hence the analytic functions satisfying the condition are of the form
$f(z) = i z^2 + c$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}$.